# Matrix property $AA^T=I=A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:** If 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(t)&i\sinh(t)\\-i\sinh(t)&\cosh(t)\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\cosh(t)=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}, \sinh(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$, and $i=\sqrt{-1}$, show that $AA^T=I=A^TA$ (so that $A^{-1}=A^T$).

I know how to do this problem in a brute-force manner (simply taking the transpose, multiplying together, etc), but I was wondering if there might be some nifty way of doing it without suffering through all of the computation. Basically, is there any "trick" that might be useful in establishing the desired equivalences?

Comment: What do you know about orthogonal matrices?

Comment: One way is to express $A$ as a matrix exponential i.e. $A=e^{B}$ for some matrix $B$. To work out what $B$ is, try Taylor expanding each of the matrix elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that helps you, but this is a $2\times2$ matrix, so you could use the following formula to calculate $A^{-1}$:
$$
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As $\det(A)=1$, you can easily calculate $A^{-1}$. Obviously it's the same as $A^{T}$. Then you're done.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that little "trick" for $2\times 2$ matrices. I ended up using the identity $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$ to tidy tidy things up a bit, but the determinant property is quite useful in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

"Brute force" is probably the best as the computation is very short.

Otherwise, if you want to avoid Hyperbolic functions, you might observe that
$$A=e^t\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\-i&1\end{bmatrix}+e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\i&1\end{bmatrix}$$
but the computation is probably even longer.